# Why does there seem to be a blanket rule that questions on God's motivations are off limits?

Tags: discussion

The question asked [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/is-there-any-scholarly-analysis-of-why-more-of-jesus-of-sayings-involve-the-ric) is as follows:

> Is there any scholarly analysis of why more of Jesus' of sayings involve the rich rather than the poor?

One comment regarding this question is as follows:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about God's motivations.

Jesus wore his motivations on his sleeves, so to speak. He spoke of his and his Father's love and care for their errant children. He told people clearly that the reason/motivation for his coming into the world was to seek and save lost people. He revealed his tenderness in some of his "I AM" statements, such as "I am the good shepherd," and he encouraged the weary and heavy laden people to come to him to find rest for their souls.

He wept over Jerusalem and said explicitly why he was doing so. He wept at Lazarus' tomb. In the Tanakh God laid out very clearly and in many places that his motivation for giving his people his Law was for their blessing, their shalom, their satisfaction and fulfillment (see, for example, Jeremiah 29:11). I could go on and on and on.

God's motivations are interspersed throughout all Scripture, and to say God's motivations are inappropriate or off-topic for this website seems, well, ludicrous.

Granted, the question would be difficult to answer, and it cannot be answered without careful study and without taking a meta approach to Jesus' teaching style, which approach is inherently risky, perhaps. On the other hand, Jesus took a meta approach to his teaching, particularly when it came to his use of parables and opaque sayings, which he characterized, in part, as deliberate obfuscation (see Matthew 13:10 ff., and Luke 8:10)! Combining that insight with insights gleaned from what other passages throughout the gospels and the rest of the Scriptures have to say about the rich and poor, a person could tease out at least some tentative theories as to why rich people figured more prominently in Jesus' communications as delimited by the OP.

Comment: minor point - Flimzy is a high-rep user, but not actually a moderator.

Comment: @DavidStratton: I do not agree with you that it's a dupe, but I shan't debate you. I gave the question an upvote, and I stand by my conviction that questions about "God's motivation" can often be answered by observing the analogy of Scripture and putting the pieces of the puzzle together vis a vis the "motivation question" in a consistent fashion. A simple counting of the number of occurrences of X, whatever X may be, is a good start for any study of the Judeo-Christian Scriptures, whether it's the # of times Jesus talked about the rich or how many "I AM" statements he made, and why. Don

Comment: @bruisedreed: OK. I posted my question on Meta, and it was marked as a dupe. I don't agree with that assessment, but then I'm not a moderator, just a contributor. Don

Comment: "Community wiki" is kind of a redundant phrase. A wiki is a community project where the content is presented as by one source, but it is drafted, reviewed, edited, and updated by many individuals. Wikipedia is a classic wiki project. On SE you can make any post a wiki. The idea is that you know part of the answer and you are inviting the community to make the perfect answer.

Comment: The above comment was a reply for a post that has now been deleted. Once you see it you can flag these comments for deletion.

Comment: @fredsbend: Thank you! How does one make an SE post a wiki?Don

Comment: There's a check mark below the post when you are first drafting it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/grCLt.png

Comment: "Community wiki" isn't a magical solution to make border-line posts on-topic.

Comment: You're right. It's not a dupe. Reopened.

Comment: @Flimzy That's not how I presented it. It is a "magical solution" to post an incomplete answer with the intent that the community would fill in the holes.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a blanket ban because [there is](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/why-does-god).

I don't know that any more explanation is needed. There are so many Meta posts that cover every possible objection to the ban that it's pointless to repeat them here.

Comment: What about the steps laid out here: [Why does God...?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9538) Can we get this in the help center sooner rather than later?